# Can we integrate Native app with PWA?

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I want to integrate my native app with PWA is that possible to do. Integrating in the sense some pages will be in Native app as Activities and some should be PWA pages i.e on clicking a button i want to open hyperlink of PWA page and display it as pwa in my native app. Is this possible?

Comment: I have native app and PWA i want to integrate them both.

Comment: In clear in my native app i am displaying navigation menus and home screens as Activities and fragments and what I want is on clicking flowable button in home screen I want to display PWA web app page.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is impossible. PWA is basically a (app-like)website in its basic form. Native app's architecture is different than a PWA. There is no IPC available b/w them. There is no way as of now, to communicate with PWA and a native app.

What you *CAN* do is create a PWA and separate native app, and deep link the pages. When a user clicks on a page link of your PWA, the user is redirected to the app. The native app gets the link information and opens the specific page. Read more about [Deep linking](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking).

Comment: You should remove the first paragraph, as the second answers the exact question that was asked. The questioner didn't ask about IPC but rather the ability to open a specific page in the native app, which is what you answered.

Comment: What the OP doesn't ask about is authentication.   I haven't tested this yet, but I believe you can bind a mobile app to a domain and, thus, gain access to the browser local storage for that domain.  Likewise, the two apps can share persistent cookies.  If you store credentials (cookie or refresh token) in the browser, the question is, can the native app use this to acquire an access token for API access?   See [Verify Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations).

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible for native application.

PWA uses service worker which is running on top of the browser, it has a script that your browser runs in the background and separate from a web page.

Answer (score -1):

I dont undestand so much of PWA, but using some logic I think its possible. Open a browser from your native APP with your PWA and it should work. I dont see a tecnical problem here.

But I think this could be a little confuse, for example: You can set a icon launcher to your PWA. There will be 2 launchers for your app in different situations?

Comment: what you are saying is to call hyperlink in default browser from my native app but i want to bypass that my pwa opening in browser and then adding the PWA app to home screen (if we do that pwa will be added as other application in my home screen). I want them to be together i.e on calling PWA from my native app PWA should be displayed in my app only.

Comment: Yeah, so I dont think this is possible. Only if you control this by development. Like a token parameter who only your app can send. But remember: the user is free to add a home screen icon to your PWA). Using some parameter, when user open your pwa from home icon you can show a message your open your native app instead.

Comment: Look, this is more a suggestion than another thing. I'm a Android/iOS developer and I dont know PWA too much